# mySQL group numeric data together with last image from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with cell viability data containing both numeric data and images (dose-response curves). The table can contain multiple rows for the same compound (uniqued by Batch ID). each row has a unique ID, as well as a date field. Now I want to group the data by Batch ID and produce the average EC50 values, but show this together with the **last** dose-response Curve generated for each compound Batch_ID. The code below will select the first Curve encountered for a particular compound Batch_ID. How can I select the last one instead, but still show it together with average EC50? Any tips appreciated!

```
SELECT Batch_ID, avg(EC50), Curve FROM CELL_VIABILITY GROUP BY Batch_ID
```

Example data:

```
ID  Batch_ID    EC50    Curve   Date
1   ABC123  6.72    blob_1  18-06-15
2   ABC123  4.74    blob_2  18-07-10
3   ABC123  8.72    blob_3  18-08-22
4   DEF456  1.95    blob_4  18-06-15
5   DEF456  1.66    blob_5  18-07-10
6   DEF456  3.06    blob_6  18-08-22
```

Expected outcome:

```
Batch_ID    EC50    Curve
ABC123     6.73    blob_3
DEF456     2.22    blob_6
```

Comment: There is not enough information to understand what last and first mean for the Curve column.

Comment: Is there any primary key in your table ? or a datetime field ? Remember that data is unordered set. Without defining an order, we cannot determine what is last, first etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that data is *unordered set*. Without defining a specific order, we cannot determine what is last, first etc.

We can use the `Date` column to define the Order. Latest updated entry (Maximum Date value) can be considered as "Last".

We can then use [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to determine the Last Curve for a specific `Batch_ID`.

```
SELECT cv1.Batch_ID, 
       AVG(cv1.EC50), 
       MAX((SELECT cv2.Curve 
           FROM CELL_VIABILITY AS cv2 
           WHERE cv2.Batch_ID = cv1.Batch_ID
           ORDER BY cv2.Date DESC LIMIT 1)) AS Last_Curve
FROM CELL_VIABILITY AS cv1
GROUP BY Batch_ID
```

---

Another approach would be using a Derived Table. We can get the last `Date` value for every `Batch_ID`. Then "Self-Join" to the table using the maximum value of the Date to get the Last `Curve`:

```
SELECT 
  cv1.Batch_ID, 
  cv1.average, 
  cv2.Curve
FROM 
(
 SELECT Batch_ID, 
        AVG(EC50) AS average, 
        MAX(Date) AS last_date 
 FROM CELL_VIABILITY
 GROUP BY Batch_ID
) AS cv1 
JOIN CELL_VIABILITY AS cv2 
  ON cv2.Batch_ID = cv1.Batch_ID AND 
     cv2.Date = cv1.last_date
```

Comment: My fault, there is a unique row ID and also a date field for each entry, if that helps. But I think your code using the ID might work fine, as the rows are always entered in order of assy date. Thank you!

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT cv2.Curve             FROM CELL_VIABILITY AS cv2             WHERE cv2.Ba' at line 3

Comment: @DrvanNostrand check the updated answer. I just added couple more parentheses around the subquery. MySQL's weirdness basically

Comment: Works like a charm, much appreciated!

Comment: @DrvanNostrand added one more possible way to the answer. You may check the second part also.

Comment: Your second solution pulls up 2070 rows from my data table, while the first one pulls up 2627 rows, which is what I also get with my simple line of code (i.e. without taking last curve into account). NB: my actual data table has many more entries than my example data above.

Comment: @DrvanNostrand Is there a possibility that some of the `Date` values are `null` ?

Comment: Yes, about half ot the entries have no Date value, so maybe better to use ID field for defining order after all?

Comment: Indeed, changing Date to ID in both solutions gives correct number of rows.

Comment: @DrvanNostrand yes. Also, you can fix the date problem by setting default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. So that you will never get null date values on future.

Comment: Cheers for that tip. A lot of the data is old with unknown date, hence the missing ones.

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to nest this correlated subquery within a CASE...WHEN statement?

Comment: @DrvanNostrand I would recommend posting a new question with sample data and expected output. It will help in formulating a query, which may be more optimized than your current approach. (nesting subquery with case when can be done , but looks inefficient)